# Addition and subtraction of chemical equations

Tags: formatting, mhchem

Is there a package that supports the addition or subtraction of chemical equations, perhaps with automatic tabbing and a alignment.  Whilst it is obvious I could set up tables or use mathmode's align feature, it seems so much more efficient to have a package handle the tabbing automatically, since it is rather predictable in this application.  `mhchem` does not seem to have such a feature...

[image]

[image]

Another advantage is you could maintain the readability of your equations and you would not have the added clutter associated with tables, especially tabs `&`, which diminish the readability of your .tex document.  And of course, the line should be automatically inserted before the last row.

Answer (score 7):

### Cancellation of species

To elaborate on Canageek's answer, yes, you can use the `cancel` package with `mhchem`, however it's a bit tricky. Specifically, using cancel inside the `\ce{}` environment will break the automagic formatting of `mhchem`, turning your species italic.

There are two ways around this:

1. You can wrap your species in `\mathrm` and then wrap that in `\cancel{}` (the easiest way)
2. You can break your equation into multiple `\ce{}` environments, and place the relevant species in `$\cancel{}$` (`\cancel{}` is supposed to be used in mathmode). This is not a good solution as it makes your equation discontiguous and messes up spacing.

   which means that you need to wrap each cancelled species in its own `\ce{}` and then place that inside a `\cancel{}`.

Here's what each option looks like:

[image: different variants of cancelled chemical equations]

Here's the code (please excuse the non-mwe nature of the code)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

Standard:
    
\ce{HCOOH_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} <=> H3O^{+}_{(aq)} + HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}\\

\texttt{$\backslash{}$cancel} inside \texttt{$\backslash{}$ce}:

\ce{\cancel{HCOOH_{(aq)}} + H2O_{(l)} <=> H3O^{+}_{(aq)} + \cancel{HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}}\\

\texttt{$\backslash{}$mathrm} inside \texttt{$\backslash{}$cancel} inside \texttt{$\backslash{}$ce}:

\ce{\cancel{\mathrm{HCOOH_{(aq)}}} + H2O_{(l)} <=> H3O^{+}_{(aq)} + \cancel{\mathrm{HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}}}\\

\texttt{$\backslash{}$cancel} outside \texttt{$\backslash{}$ce}:

$\cancel{\ce{HCOOH_{(aq)}}}$ \ce{+ H2O_{(l)} <=> H3O^{+}_{(aq)} +} $\cancel{\ce{HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}}$
\end{document}
```

As you can see, this diminishes readability profoundly :(

You can change the colour of the cancellation line [via `\renewcommand{\CancelColor}`](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf), which is a bit of a pain.

### Alignment

I was not sure if your reference to align in mathmode meant that you were using mathmode in `align` to manually set chemical equations, rather than `mhchem`, but `mhchem` has the [`\cee` environment](http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf), which acts like a the `\ce` environment but allows you to use `&` as an alignment point in an `align` environment. It seems fairly simple.

Putting it all together:

[image: aligned equations]

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}


    \begin{align*}
    \centering
    \cee{\cancel{\mathrm{HCOOH_{(aq)}}} + H2O_{(l)} &<=> H3O^{+}_{(aq)} + \cancel{\mathrm{HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}}}\\
    \cee{\cancel{\mathrm{HCOO^{-}_{(aq)}}} + H2O_{(l)} &<=> \cancel{\mathrm{HCOOH_{(aq)}}} + OH^{-}_{(aq)}}\\
    \hline{}
    \cee{H2O_{(l)} + H2O_{(l)} &<=> H3O^{+} + OH^{-}_{(aq)}}    
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Getting the `\hline` to a more sensible length and adjusting the spacing between formulae is left as an exercise to the interested reader (I don't know, but someone else probably does. It's a start.)

Hope this is of some use.

Comment: Would it be possible to borrow some code from siunitx to get a similar effect, where you can use /cancel inside of the environment without breaking it? Or are the two environments too dissimilar?

Comment: @Canageek - I don't know. A long-term solution would consist of a new version of `mhchem`. A simple fix is to define a new cancel command for use in the `\ce` environment. For example: `\newcommand{\canceq}[1]{\cancel{\mathrm{#1}}}`. So now you can just use `\canceq{HCOO^{-}}` which is somewhat nicer.

Answer (score 5):

I came about a way to achieve what you want, provided by Clemens Niederberger, that uses his `chemmacros` package and `cancel` and can be found on [mychemistry.eu](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2012/03/cancelling-compounds/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,cancel}

\let\oldcancel\cancel
\renewcommand\cancel[1][black]{%
  \def\CancelColor{\color{#1}}%
  \oldcancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \ch{\cancel[blue]{HCOOH\aq} + H2O\lqd{}  &<=> H3O^+\aq{} + \cancel[red]{HCOO^-\aq}} \\
  \ch{\cancel[red]{HCOO^-\aq} + H2O\lqd{} &<=> \cancel[blue]{HCOOH\aq} + OH^-\aq}\\[-1ex]
  \cline{1-2}
  \ch{H2O\lqd{} + H2O\lqd{} &<=> H3O^+\aq{} + OH^-\aq}    
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the addition and subtraction of chemical formula themselves, but there is the cancel package which can probably provide the ah, cancelling.

Answer (score 0):

You mention readability of the code. You could redefine (or activate) single characters to help here. The following is definitely not optimal, but redefines `|` and `>` to mean `+` and `\rightarrow` with the appropriate column alignment from an array:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\begin{document}
\[
  \catcode`\|=\active \newcommand{|}{&+&}
  \catcode`\>=\active \renewcommand{>}{&\rightarrow&}
\begin{array}{*{19}{@{\,}c}}
  &&&&   \ce{10e-} | \ce{16H+} | \ce{2MnO_4-} > \ce{2Mn^2+} | \ce{8H_2O} \\
  &&&&&& \ce{5H_2O} | \ce{5H_2SO_3} > \ce{5SO_4^2-} | \ce{20H+} | \ce{10e-} \\ \hline
  \ce{10e-} | \ce{16H+} | \ce{2MnO_4-} | \ce{5H_2O} | \ce{5H_2SO_3} >  
    \ce{2Mn^2+} | \ce{8H_2O} | \ce{5SO_4^2-} | \ce{20H+} | \ce{10e-}
\end{array}
\]
```

[image: Alignment of chemical compounds]

Of course, the regular cancelling (via the [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel)) still holds, if required. The problem I'm having, hence noting this as sub-optimal, is from the [`mhchem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) that actively changes `+` and `-` (to superscripts), forcing the use of `|` for the addition of chemical compounds. This needs some further investigation.