# using \cancel within a mhchem command italicizes text (how to prevent?)

Tags: mhchem, cancel

The text being cancelled is italicized when the following code is printed. How do I prevent this? Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}       
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % insert chem equations
\usepackage{cancel} %strike out text

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cee{
\cancel{Mg_{(s)}} + 1/2O_{(g)} + &-> MgO_{(s)} \\
MgO_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} \\
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30140/21344
The main problem is that `\cancel` detects math mode in use because you're inside `\cee`. This breaks `mhchem`s automatic formatting of the species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new command that uses `\ce` inside `\cancel` to prevent turning the argument into math mode:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}       
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % insert chem equations
\usepackage{cancel} %strike out text

\newcommand\Cancel[1]{\cancel{\ce{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cee{
\Cancel{Mg_{(s)}} + 1/2O_{(g)} + &-> MgO_{(s)} \\
MgO_{(s)} + 2HCl_{(aq)} &-> MgCl2_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} \\
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]